# How do I resolve error TF204017 that is preventing deletion of a workspace?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am currently unable to delete a TFVC workspace on my local Windows 10 machine. It's a private workspace that I created. The machine is not domain joined and I am an administrator on the machine. I'm getting the following error:

```
D:\Projects\Active\SPE-DEV>tf workspace /delete MYWORKSPACE
A deleted workspace cannot be recovered.
Workspace 'MYWORKSPACE' on server 'https://ourcompany.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection' has 0 pending change(s).
Are you sure you want to delete the workspace? (Yes/No) y
TF204017: The operation cannot be completed because the user (Greg Enslow) does not have one or more required permission
s (Administer) for workspace MYWORKSPACE;Greg Enslow.
```

I get the same message if I try to delete it from within the Visual Studio UI. I can manually delete all the files and folders in the workspace but TFS recreates a the root folder with a hidden $tf folder.

This morning I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (only had a trial license) and installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional (my company has a license for this). I'm sure this is a factor but my VS Team Services permissions haven't changed at all.

Comment: tf workspaces command which can remove the specified workspace entries for the specified server from the client cache, maybe you can run it:
tf workspaces /remove:(*|workspace1[,workspace2,...]) /collection:(*|TeamProjectCollectionUrl)

Answer (score 6):

You can first change that MYWORKSPACE to be a public workspace, then run the "tf workspace /delete MYWORKSPACE" command again.

To change the workspace to be a public workspace, please go to Manage Workspace dialog, select the workspace and click Advanced.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, no. I had tried this a while back and it didn't make any difference. I moved this question to MS Connects because it was a much bigger problem than I initially realized. Here's a link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48d38556-32cb-4214-a849-a51cc148ea23/cant-access-visual-studio-online-after-switching-from-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-to-visual?forum=TFService

Comment: This setting is worked to get the the access of source code.

Comment: This setting worked for me after having to create a new profile on my computer