# The operation could not be completed because the user does not have one or more required permissions for workspace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional on Windows 7. Code is being synced with TFS on visualstudio.com so I have got repository something like

> http://myrepo.visualstudio.com

Primary hotmail account is primary@hotmail.com which was working fine as I was able go "Check In "code changes.

Then I added another user to repository (secondary@hotmail.com) gave it full permission and then tried to Check In code using this account in Visual Studio but I get error:

> The operation could not be completed because the user does not have
> one or more required permissions for workspace

I have completely deleted browser cache, restarted PC and then logged in again using new account in VS 2012 but still same issue. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the error info, you may need to change `your workspace` to **be a public workspace**(A fully public workspace can be used, checked in, and administered by any valid user).

To change the workspace to be a public workspace, please go to `Manage Workspace dialog`, select the workspace and click `Advanced`. 
[image]

If above steps still can't work. Try to delete all login info stored in **Credential Manager** via `Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager.` More details you can refer this link:[How can I change the default credentials used to connect to Visual Studio Online (TFSPreview) when loading Visual Studio up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407668/how-can-i-change-the-default-credentials-used-to-connect-to-visual-studio-online)

Comment: This [was the solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132821/), but it might be questionable to change one’s own private workspace to a public one.